# iOS removing MKMapView overlays not working

Tags: ios, mkmapview, overlay, android-mapview

I would like to remove all the overlays of my map at one point, and I tried different ways but it never works.

Last try I did `[self.mapView removeOverlays:self.mapView.overlays];` and it still doesn't work. Any idea how I can remove those overlays?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

I have the error: `malloc: *** error for object 0x5adc0c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I think I know why, but don't really know how to fix it...
Here is the code when I need to draw another line on my mapView:

```
// Create a c array of points. 
MKMapPoint *pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * 2);

// Create 2 points.
MKMapPoint startPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(oldLatitude, oldLongitude));
MKMapPoint endPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLatitude, newLongitude));

// Fill the array.
pointsArray[0] = startPoint;
pointsArray[1] = endPoint;

// Erase polyline and polyline view if not nil.
if (self.routeLine != nil) {
    [_routeLine release];
    self.routeLine = nil;
}

if (self.routeLineView != nil) {
    [_routeLineView release];
    self.routeLineView = nil;
}

// Create the polyline based on the array of points.
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];

// Add overlay to map.
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];

// clear the memory allocated earlier for the points.
free(pointsArray);

// Save old coordinates.
oldLatitude = newLatitude;
oldLongitude = newLongitude;
```

So I release the `routeLine` object which is the previous overlay. So when I tried to remove it, it crashes because it has already been deallocated.

Here is the code for the mapView delegate for adding overlay views:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

    if(overlay == _routeLine) {
        // If we have not yet created an overlay view for this overlay, create it now. 
        if(self.routeLineView == nil) {
            self.routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:_routeLine] autorelease];

            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];

            // Size of the trace.
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = routeLineWidth;
        }

        overlayView = self.routeLineView;
    }

    return overlayView;
}
```

If you guys know how I can fix this issue, removing all overlays from my MKMapView it would be awesome!

**UPDATE 2**

I tried not releasing my `routeLine` and `routeLineView` objects and it works now. It seems like there are no leaks too. So now I'm doing this:

```
// Erase polyline and polyline view if not nil.
if (self.routeLine != nil) {
    //[_routeLine release];
    self.routeLine = nil;
}

if (self.routeLineView != nil) {
    //[_routeLineView release];
    self.routeLineView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `removeOverlays:`, the map view will release the MKOverlay and MKOverlayView objects.

You hold your own references to these in `_routeLine` and `_routeLineView`.

After `removeOverlays:` is called, your variables will be pointing to already-released memory.  When you re-create the polyline, you are over-releasing which then results in a crash.

So remove the `release` calls:

```
if (_routeLine != nil) {
    [_routeLine release];  // <-- remove this
    self.routeLine = nil;
}

if (_routeLineView != nil) {
    [_routeLineView release];  // <-- remove this
    self.routeLineView = nil;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did :)
Thanks a lot @Anna Karenina!

Answer (score 7):

When you step through the code in the debugger, where does the error show up?

One thought, you may have an issue with your retain/release cycle for `self.routeLine` and `self.routeLineView`. Assuming they are properties with a `retain` attribute, when you do

```
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
```

your synthesized accessor is retaining the new `MKPolyline` object. That object will also have a retain/autorelease pair from the convenience method that created it. When this method gets called again and you call the

```
if (self.routeLine != nil) {
    [_routeLine release];
    self.routeLine = nil;
}
```

code, you will end up releasing the variable twice, the first with the explicit `[_routeLine release]` call and the second with the synthesized accessor on the `self.routeLine = nil;` call. It will stay in memory, but will crash the app when your autorelease pool is drained.

In most cases, to clear all the overlays on an `MKMapView` (named `mapView` in this sample), I'd do something like the following:

```
for (id<MKOverlay> overlayToRemove in mapView.overlays)
{
   if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[OverlayClassToRemove class]])
   {
       [mapView removeOverlay:overlayToRemove];
   }
}
```

Comment: The `polylineWithPoints:count:` method takes a C array of MKMapPoint structs.

Comment: I like the way to remove the overlays you told me, and thought it would work, or at least not crash the app. But it did and I have the same error.
@Anna Karenina The way I store the points is right then? I tried to store in a `NSArray` and can't even add this type of object in it anyway.

Comment: @Dachmt and @Anna Karenina I stand corrected. That's what I get for guessing about things I haven't done myself. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I did remove the `[_routeLine release];` and `[_routeLineView release];` and it works now. Please look at **UPDATE 2** and let me know if you think if there is something wrong.

Comment: @Dachmt Makes sense. Sorry I didn't finish my edit before you figured that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 extenstion

```
extension MKMapView
{
    func removeAllOverlay(){
        for overlay:MKOverlay in self.overlays  {
            self.remove(overlay)
        }
    }

}
```